# Missing file in res>layout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adk

I'm currently using eclipse to build android apps, but according to the tutorial, there will file named main.xml in res>layout to create the design of my apps. However my layout is empty.

Comment: Post more detail, please

Comment: so, you check the `layout` folder under `res` and you find the `layout` folder empty, there has no `xml` named `activity_main.xml`, am I right?

Comment: yes, the folder is empty.

Comment: I'm currently this tutorial as my first apps ->  http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.ch/2012/12/first-android-app-step-by-step.html However, on the Use externalized Strings part, i can't find my main.xml under my layout forlder

Answer (score 1):

I had posted about the same issue with extra information, but it was deleted. However, I found a solution so you can get the layout folder populated with the blank activity.

Instead of using the ADT package, download Eclipse and the SDK separately. Follow the details [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Configure), but [download and unpack the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) first. Click the DOWNLOAD FOR OTHER PLATFORMS link.

You will also need the location of your java JRE bin folder.

I hope that helps,

Lee.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project based on a template and everything will be set up as expected. It sounds like you may be new to Android. I would suggest reading through the documentation for building your first app. It will tell you all you need to know.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: I believe that's precisely what this user is trying to do. I encountered this same problem trying to do the "build your first app" for beginners tutorial and it doesn't work because the files they tell you to access are not present after following the directions to a T.